# Heavy database-query page, best practice

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this task on hand, a page which essentially can be called a Dashboard. It has many blocks of information and all of this information needs to be queried from database.

I'm thinking of best practice approach towards Models when it comes to Laravel. Controllers and Views are simple: one controller, structure of views.

Thing to mentioned, this is a fresh Laravel, no pre-existing Model exists, however database big and is full of records and this page can be called a micro-service - meant to represent the data in a dashboard format.

Should I be doing Eloquent models to map as much as I can and use it inside my Controller to get the data or Query Builder would be better option considering I don't need migration and this Laravel build will never do Writes, only Reads.

Any input from gurus much appreciated.

Comment: The only way to know what would be fast enough for you is to write some code and benchmark it. The size of the database don't matter much, only the size of your result-set

Comment: @rypskar agree. As ~Kirk Bread says, it's opinion based. I personally believe in this case query builder is better option because 1) no migration 2) advanced queries, lots of join. What would be your personal approach?

Comment: Personally I would probably use query builder or raw query, but that is because I like writing SQL and am faster at writing SQL than to set up eloquent models

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check `Laravel's repositories` pattern. This pattern is used when you are working with database (storing, retrieving...). I think it would be perfect to use in your case.

Comment: Interesting, can you link me up @Epsilon47?

Comment: Sure, there is an article about repositories:
http://shawnmc.cool/the-repository-pattern but this question is better discussed in the article here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-the-difference-between-a-model-and-a-repository . I really like the "michaeldyrynda"'s answer. The repositories definitelly have more advantages and if you have never used them before you may find it confusing. I would recommend you to read a couple more articles about that